# CUDA invalid device function

Tags: cuda, nvidia

I get an `thrust::system::system_error invalid device function` while trying to access a device vector with `thrust::device_vector< int > labels_d(width*height);`

In my CMakeFile I've written 
`SET(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS};-gencode arch=compute_20,code=compute_20)` 
And also tried different settings there. 
So I guess it has something to do with my GPU (a Quadro FX 580) and CUDA maybe a pointer to my device is wrong or something...

Does anybody have a clue on what to change to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to find out that my GPU simply is too old for `arch=compute_20`, and so I have to use  `arch=compute_11`.

Comment: @loretoparisi I'm sorry, but that was nearly one year ago. But i vaguely remember that I was googling for a few hours to find it in a table somewhere on the nvidia sites. But I don't know any URL anymore. Maybe just look for your GPU and with some luck you will find which arch it can use.

Comment: Thanks @sven, I have found out somewhere a list, but it's actually not so easy to auto-detect this from your `/proc/cpuinfo`.